# Probabilty concerning two normal distributed random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Consider the two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ where each random variable is 3-dimensionally normal distributed with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\Sigma_X)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mathbf{\mu}},\Sigma_Y)$, with covariance matrices $\Sigma_X$ and $\Sigma_Y$ and mean $\mathbf{0} $ and $\mathbf{\mu},$ respectively.

My Question is: What is the probability that $X$ and $Y$ have a distance that is smaller than the number $r$, i.e. $P(\lVert X - Y \rVert^2 < r^2) $?
I am also particularly interested in the  special cases $\Sigma_X = \sigma_X^2 \mathbf{I} $ and $\Sigma_Y = \sigma_Y^2 \mathbf{I} $.

Comment: $X-Y\sim N(-\mu,\Sigma_X+\Sigma_Y)$, so you are left with a single integral.

Comment: A.S. Thank you for your comment. However, I am stuck in solving this integral and cannot see an easy or elegant way to solve it.

Comment: For your special case, you have something like a scaled [noncentral chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution)

Comment: In your special case (for $\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2=1$, $Z_i$ standard 1-D normals and $\mu=(0,0,d)$): $P=P(Z_1^2+Z_2^2+(Z_3-d)^2<r^2)$. You know $P(Z_1^2+Z_2^2<r^2)$ so you are left with a single 1-D integral.